# prefix is define in http.sh script but apache install it default location

Tags: apache

i have a query in apache server installation when ever i install the apache server in OEL 6.2 64bit its install in the default directory is path is `/usr/local/apache2`
i tried many times but its still install in the default directory
 i define the different prefix is `--prefix=/u2/usr/app2/apache1` in the `http.sh` script and `./configure` it its successfuly configured with out any error an then

```
make 
make install
```

but install on it default location that is `/usr/local/apache2` not in mine specify location
kinldy give me advise to resolve this problem
thank you
and waiting for your response

Comment: Can you try to clean your compilation directory using `make clean`?

Comment: Would it be feasible to have a `gist` of http.sh or some extract?

Comment: Dear Thierry, you mention the two solutions i have tried only one that is make clean in /httpd2.2 directory but result is same its install in default location and another one i cant not understand gist http.sh

Answer (score 0):

Can you run the installation as follow:

```
./configure --prefix=/u2/usr/app2/apache1 && make && make install
```

Before that, make sure the parent directory exists and it is writable for current user:

```
`mkdir -p /u2/usr/app2 && chown `whoami` /u2/usr/app2 && chmod 700 /u2/usr/app2`
```

Comment: Thank you very much its install on the specify location